# asp.net mvc example with db

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know the basics of MVC. But I am looking for an asp.net mvc example with db.

The following example explains the same - but the db is within the app_data folder. But in real practice, as u know, we will use an external SQL server for this

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs

Can u pl site an example - which explains asp.net mvc with db (just save & retrieve)

Comment: If you are able to understand the example in above link, then you can also implement it with external database. just try a bit harder. :)

Comment: It doesn't matter where the DB file is located. The MVC application cares only about the connection string. If you are using a DB on a remote machine, just update the connection string to point to that.

Answer (score 0):

It might not completely meet your question but it is quit usual to use Entity Framework or NHibernate to manage your database

See [ASP.Net site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc) or [the Entity Framework tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Maybe you can find some other answers at that site.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference on the mvc side. You just have a different connection string to point to a sql server instead of a file inside app_data folder.

Create the same database on you local sql server express and change the [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) to point there. You'll see that will work the same.

In order to make your life easier, you can download [SQL ServerManagement Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593) (this is 2008 version)